# Nontrivial B program

Tags: history, programming, unix

I have been able to find very little about the B programming language online. the predominant resources seem incomplete, particularly in regards to standard library functions. I have not been able find example programs longer than a handful of lines.

The [Wikipedia article for B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language)) mentions a MUD written in B, as well as its usage in other contexts.

Has any nontrivial B code survived to this day?

Comment: I suppose [Thompson's reference manual](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/kbman.html) to be as definitive as it gets.  If there are no major examples, that's likely because it was a parochial language that was replaced relatively quickly.

Comment: apparently, B saw usage as late as the year 2000.

Comment: [This doc](https://www.thinkage.ca/gcos/expl/b/manu/manu.html) says it was used on GCOS8.

Comment: A printer listing for AberMUD does exist, but it has not been scanned.  Here's some information: https://github.com/larsbrinkhoff/abermud/tree/master/abermud1

Comment: @another-dave, Thinkage is still in business right?  As far as I understand, Steve Johnson was on sabbatical from Bell Labs in U Waterloo and brought B with him.  A group of people at the university picked up the language and started a business.

Comment: @LarsBrinkhoff - It looks that way.  It was news to me that B ever escaped from early Unix.

Answer (score 10):

The first version of AberMUD was written in B (by Alan Cox of Linux fame, amongst others), and has survived as a printer listing.  Here is some information:
https://github.com/larsbrinkhoff/abermud/tree/master/abermud1

The Canadian company Thinkage offers B tools for GCOS:
https://www.thinkage.ca/gcos/product-uwtools.htm
It's a spinoff from University of Waterloo which has a history of using B going back to when Steve Johnson, the author of Yacc, was there in 1973.